# Magento - allowing customer to use their FedEx account

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, fedex

I'm working on a Magento site which ships products via FedEx.  When an order is purchased, it should charge the store's FedEx account, allow the store to print a shipping label, and offer tracking information on the website.

In addition, the customer should also have the option of charging the shipping costs (NOT the product costs) to their FedEx account instead.

Is there an existing extension which has all these features, or one which can easily be configured to use the customer's FedEx account instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inchoo has some interesting article regarding FedEx integration. You can read all about it over on their [blog post](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-fedex-shipping-in-magento/) it covers the default magento FedEx options. Anything more and you will probably need to extend the existing implementation and develop a new module.

Inside the module you can setup your FedEx account for the store and it generally has plenty of needed options. Probably it can't handle your second request, charging the customer FedEx account.

The only FedEx extensions are in [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/filter/all?query=fedex) which is basically the only place to find and get extensions from other developers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The ability to print shipping labels is really important, so I may end up purchasing one of the advanced extensions.  I guess I'll have to do some custom modifications to that so customers can charge the shipping costs to their FedEx account instead.

Comment: To your point about Magento Connect, I've downloaded code from GitHub before, however it's usually a last resort ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This extension fulfills all of your requirements, except allowing the customer to bill to his FedEx account number:
   http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-extension.html

The print label page, would allow you to "Bill to Reciever" and enter their account number.  We could provide a quote for an enhancement to allow the user to provide account number upon checkout. One concern I had is how would we validate that it's a valid account number?  (ie fraud)

The existing extension integrates Magento with all the latest FedEx APIs.  One of the few extensions that print official FedEx shipping labels with bar codes.

Answer (score 0):

Our extension now supports multiple opitons for billing transportaion costs, customs/duties costs, and COD (Cash On Delivery).

We have the most extensive Magento FedEx extension available:

http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-extension.html

It also fully supports customers based in India, Europe, etc.. ANY where that FedEx supports our extension does too.